# Splitting string into linked words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffold

So I have standart scaffold cycle that prints a string of tags of a meet.

```
<% @meets.each do |meet| %>
      <p class="MeetTags"><%= meet.tags %></p>
   <% end %>
```

How can I separate string of for example 3 words, so that each would be in separate box.
Thank you!

Comment: If you have an answer that worked, you should accept it (click on the check mark next to the answer that worked best)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is that `meet.tags` is an array, so you're telling rails to display the array: that's why you're seeing the square braces.

If you want to split tags into groups of 3, and then show them separated by spaces, you could do this:

```
<% @meets.each do |meet| %>
  <% tag_arr = meet.tags.split(' ') %>
  <% tag_arr.in_groups_of_3.each do |tag_subarr|%>
   <p class="MeetTags"><%= tag_subarr.reject(&:blank?).join(" ") %></p>
  <%end%>
<% end %>
```

I'm using `.reject(&:blank?)` because the `in_groups_of` method will pad the last subarray out with nil, which will mess up your formatting, and maybe cause other problems if you try and do anything with the member elements of tag_subarr.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some think like

```
<% @meets.each do |meet| %>
  <% meet_tags = meet.tags.split(' ') %>
  <% meet_tags.each do |meet_tag|%>
   <p class="MeetTags"><%= meet_tag %></p>
  <%end%>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your tags are joined with space:

```
<% @meets.each do |meet| %>
  <% meet.tags.split(' ').each do |word| %>
    <p class="MeetTags"><%= word %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: And how can I get eat coffee lunch instead of  ["eat coffee lunch"]

Comment: @DanieliusVisockas change comma into space in `split` 'condition', just as I did in edited answer.

Comment: I want to get rid of [ and " symbols. If I change space to comma I get ["eat", "coffee", "lunch"]

Comment: @DanieliusVisockas You mean, you get these in HTML?

Comment: Yes, I've pasted it from my site.

Comment: @DanieliusVisockas ok, it was my mistake. Please check out edited answer.

Comment: Thank you, symbols to complete comment